# Is it a red flag to see data typecast in query plan?

Tags: postgresql, index, explain

In a query plan I see the type of a row being cast. There's an index that should be used, and isn't. Is the typecast a red flag?

The table has had an ANALYZE and has 110 million rows. Of these, 10% match the query.

Here's the full explain:

```
explain select * from item_info where subtype = 'Dataset';

                                     QUERY PLAN
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Gather  (cost=1000.00..1592021.24 rows=1320650 width=27)
   Workers Planned: 2
   ->  Parallel Seq Scan on item_info  (cost=0.00..1458956.24 rows=550271 width=27)
         Filter: ((subtype)::text = 'Dataset'::text)
(4 rows)

Time: 0.652 ms=> \d item_info
                     Table "public.item_info"
    Column    |       Type        | Collation | Nullable | Default
--------------+-------------------+-----------+----------+---------
 root_item_pk | bigint            |           | not null |
 type         | character varying |           |          |
 subtype      | character varying |           |          |
Indexes:
    "item_info_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (root_item_pk)
    "item_info_subtype_idx" btree (subtype)
    "item_info_type_idx" btree (type)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. At least not between varchar and text. The fact that it expects 1320650 rows might be a red flag though.  Why use an index if you need to read a huge chunk of the table anyway?

Comment: The query matches about 10% of the rows, for what it's worth. This query was boiled down from a larger slow query, and this filter was part of a join. The  question was about whether I should worry about the typecast specifically. Thanks for your confirmation on that.

Comment: Unless the pg_stats.correlation is high, reading 10% of the tuples usually means reading 100% (or more, depending on effective_io_cache) of the table, only in random IO fashion rather than sequential fashion.  It would be nice if EXPLAIN could suppress the display of non-problematic casts like this one, so that it would serve as a red flag.

Comment: Thanks, this is really useful information!